# Perplexing Javascript Integer comparison bug

Tags: javascript, comparison, integer, int, comparison-operators

This is probably a really simple thing but I can't for the life of me figure out or find anything remotely like the issue. I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm doing some simple form validation on HTML fields. The two problems at hand are these:

```
    if(minSquare.search(intCheck) == -1 || minSquare < 500 || minSquare > 5000 || minSquare > maxSquare)
    {
        errorPrint.innerHTML += "Incorrect minimum square feet amount <br />";
        errors++;
    }

    if(maxSquare.search(intCheck) == -1 || maxSquare > 5000 || maxSquare < 500)
    {
        errorPrint.innerHTML += "Incorrect maximum square feet amount <br />";
        errors++;
    }
```

minSquare/maxSquare are the values taken from the HTML fields. As you can see the square feet values (in a real estate setting) are supposed to be between 500-5000 and have to be an integer. The logic is there, but every time I submit the form, the error for incorrect minimum square feet prints if the value is **below 1,000 despite the lower limit being 500.** This is the same case for another pair of fields in that if the value is below 100,000, it won't print despite its own lower limit being 30,000.

For some reason when I enter 500 for the minimum amount and 5000 for the maximum amount (the proper range), it will submit no problem. But if I enter say, 501 and 5000 it will throw an error for the minimum value. I have no idea why this is happening. I don't think it's a browser issue; tried on both Chrome and Firefox, same problem. Any help appreciated; the more stupid the problem the quicker I can close this up =)

**EDIT:** Fixed the problem. Knew it was simple. As per advice below, I just needed to parse the inputs and then I needed to get rid of the RegExp search method that would only work if the variable being searched is a string. Thanks to those who replied.

Comment: If you're taking them directly from an HTML field, are you converting them into number types (via `parseInt` or `parseFloat`)?

Comment: What does that "search" function do?

Comment: @NickHusher I did not convert them, good catch! I just tried parseInt on the aforementioned fields, and while no errors came up, I left in errors for other fields for testing purposes and upon submitting, the errors are quickly displayed and then cleared (as per my algorithm of clearing the <div> element where they're printed) while the form clears (when it shouldn't). Another bug to deal with!

Comment: @Pointy It is a RegExp method that checks to see if the input is an integer (intCheck defined as /^\d+$/).